# Problema con dateFormat en Datepicker Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

Por necesidades visuales configure el datepicker para que el formato de fecha solo muestre **dd/mm** en el input y el valor completo lo estoy almacenando en un atributo del input de la siguiente manera:

```
<input name="ini_date_0_0" id="ini_date_0_0" class="date-picker hasDatepicker" valor="31/1/2022">
```

El problema es que cuando vuelvo a seleccionar la fecha el datepicker al solo tener dia y mes en el valor entonces asume que corresponde al año en curso por lo que pasaría por ejemplo de **"31/1/2022"** a **"31-1-2021"**.

Existiría alguna manera de darle o bien el valor almacenado para que se asigne al hacer click, que de cualquier otra forma asi sea manejando la fecha completa se muestren en el input solo el dd-mm o bien que como sea el datepicker entienda a que año debería apuntar correctamente?

Mi codigo JavaScript es el siguiente:

```
//Definiciones iniciales del datepicker
        jQuery(function() {
            
            //Establecemos texto de traduccion para region
            jQuery.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                closeText: 'Cerrar',
                prevText: '< Ant',
                nextText: 'Sig >',
                currentText: 'Hoy',
                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
                weekHeader: 'N°',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''
            };
            
            //Establecemos la region actual
            jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional['es']);
            
            DatePickerNew();
        });
        
        function DatePickerNew()
        {
            jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker( {
                changeMonth: false,
                changeYear: false,
                showWeek: true,
                showButtonPanel: false,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm',
                
                beforeShow: function(dateText, inst){
                    //valor = ( this.getAttribute("valor") ).split("/");
                    //jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
                },
                
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
                    
                    this.setAttribute("valor", inst.selectedDay+"/"+(inst.selectedMonth+1)+"/"+inst.selectedYear)
                    
                    //alert(inst.selectedYear+"/"+inst.selectedMonth+"/"+inst.selectedDay)
                }
            });
        }
```

Considere usar el evento beforeShow pero no tengo muy claro como aplicaría

Comment: Por favor, puedes cargar mas de tu codigo HTML para imitar tu codigo?

Comment: Pues de lo que sea relevante supongo que lo único que podría restar seria código CSS o la hoja de estilos del jquery-ui, pero a nivel de HTML realmente no habria nada relevante realmente... De igual manera ya logre resolver mi problema, ya ahora publico mi solución :D

Answer (score 1):

Ya logre resolver el inconveniente, el problema es que independientemente del código, mientras que el formato se maneje '**dd/mm**' aun dándole set al datepicker con información del año este ignorará dicho dato y asumirá el año en curso. Mi solución fue hacer un pequeño evento beforeShow de la siguiente manera

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    
    if(input.getAttribute("data-selectedDate") != null)
    {
        input.setAttribute("style", "padding-left: 100%; padding-right: 0;");
        
        jQuery(".date-picker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yyyy" );
        
        objStartDate = new Date( input.getAttribute("data-selectedDate") )
        
        jQuery(input).datepicker("setDate", objStartDate );
        
    }
}
```

Y modificando el evento onClose

```
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    
    //Cambiamos el formato de la fecha a mostrar
    jQuery(".date-picker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm" );
    
    alert(inst.selectedYear+","+(inst.selectedMonth+1)+","+(inst.selectedDay));
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    
    //this.setAttribute("valor", inst.selectedDay+"/"+(inst.selectedMonth+1)+"/"+inst.selectedYear)
    this.setAttribute("data-selectedDate", inst.selectedYear+","+(inst.selectedMonth+1)+","+(inst.selectedDay) );
    
    this.setAttribute("style", "");
},
```